# Nuxt Apollo module request authorization header with double 'Bearer '

Tags: authentication, token, nuxt.js, apollo, auth0

In my Nuxt app I have auth token stored in my cookie named 'auth._token.auth0'. It looks like:

```
Bearer%20eyJhbGciO...
```

And I want to use this token in my apollo requests authorization header, so I configured my apollo module:

```
apollo: {
    clientConfigs: {
        default: {
            httpEndpoint: process.env.GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT,
            httpLinkOptions: {
                credentials: 'same-origin'
            },
            tokenName: 'auth._token.auth0'
        }
    }
},
```

and it successfully attaches token from cookie to apollo authorization header, but it adds another 'Bearer ' string, so graphql returns Malformed Authorization header error, because authorization header looks like:

```
authorization: Bearer Bearer eyJhbGciOi...
```

Any ideas how to solve this issue in nuxt apollo module or nuxt auth module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by adding `authenticationType: ''` in config:

```
apollo: {
    clientConfigs: {
        default: {
            httpEndpoint: process.env.GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT,
            httpLinkOptions: {
                credentials: 'same-origin'
            },
            tokenName: 'auth._token.auth0'
        }
    },
    authenticationType: ''
},
```